# Pandas: aggregate based on filter on another column

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
Month   Fruit   Sales
1       Apple   45
1       Bananas 12
3       Apple   6
1       Kiwi    34
12      Melon   12
```

I'm trying to get a dataframe that goes like this

```
Fruit         Sales (month=1)     Sales (month=2)
Apple         55                  65
Bananas       12                  102
Kiwi          54                  78
Melon         132                 43
```

Right now I have

```
df=df.groupby(['Fruit']).agg({'Sales':np.sum}).reset_index()
```

There has to be some way to filter the arguments within agg() based on the "Month" variable. I just haven't been able to find it in the docs. Any help?

Edit:
Thanks for the solutions. To complicate things, I would like to sum up another column as well. Example:

```
Month    Fruit    Sales  Revenue
1       Apple    45     45
1       Bananas  12     12
3       Apple    6      6
1       Kiwi     34     34
12      Melon    12     12
```

The preferred output would be similar to

```
            Sales      Revenue
     Fruit   1  3  12  1   3  12
0    Apple  61  6   0  61  6  0
1  Bananas  12  6   0  12  6  0
2     Kiwi  34  0   0  34  0  0
3    Melon   0  0  12  0   0  12
```

I managed to get this with `df.pivot_table(values=['Sales','Revenue'], index='Fruit', columns=['Month'], aggfunc='np.sum').reset_index()`, so my problem is resolved.

I attempted the same thing with `df.groupby(['Fruit', 'Month'])['Sales','Revenue'].sum().unstack('Month', fill_value=0).rename_axis(None, 1).reset_index()`, but this throws a TypeError. Can the above operation be done with `groupby` as well?

Comment: This is not how SO works, show us what snippet you have scratched together thus far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer the updated question you should do things a little differently.
First [group by](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the elements that should be the columns afterwards (Month and Fruit). Then calculate the sum of those groups and [unstack](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) the DataFrame afterwards which leaves the Fruit column as the index column.

```
data = '''
Month    Fruit   Sales  Revenue
1       Apple    45     45
1       Bananas  12     12
1       Apple    16     16
3       Apple    6      6
1       Kiwi     34     34
3       Bananas  6      6
12      Melon    12     12
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

df.groupby(['Month', 'Fruit'])\
    .sum()\
    .unstack(level=0)
```

Result

```
        Sales            Revenue           
Month      1    3     12      1    3     12
Fruit                                      
Apple    61.0  6.0   NaN    61.0  6.0   NaN
Bananas  12.0  6.0   NaN    12.0  6.0   NaN
Kiwi     34.0  NaN   NaN    34.0  NaN   NaN
Melon     NaN  NaN  12.0     NaN  NaN  12.0
```

### old answer

Use the [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) method:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = '''\
Month Fruit  Sales
1       Apple   45
1       Bananas 12
1       Apple   16
3       Apple   6
1       Kiwi    34
3       Bananas 6
12      Melon   12
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

df.pivot_table('Sales', index='Fruit', columns=['Month'], aggfunc='sum')
```

Result:

```
Month      1    3     12
Fruit                   
Apple    61.0  6.0   NaN
Bananas  12.0  6.0   NaN
Kiwi     34.0  NaN   NaN
Melon     NaN  NaN  12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [177]: df
Out[177]:
   Month    Fruit  Sales  Revenue
0      1    Apple     45       45
1      1  Bananas     12       12
2      3    Apple      6        6
3      1     Kiwi     34       34
4     12    Melon     12       12

In [178]: df.groupby(['Fruit', 'Month'])[['Sales','Revenue']].sum().unstack('Month', fill_value=0)
Out[178]:
        Sales        Revenue
Month      1  3   12      1  3   12
Fruit
Apple      45  6   0      45  6   0
Bananas    12  0   0      12  0   0
Kiwi       34  0   0      34  0   0
Melon       0  0  12       0  0  12
```

**OLD answer:**

Alternatively youcan use `groupby()` + `unstack()`:

```
In [206]: df.groupby(['Fruit', 'Month'])['Sales'].sum().unstack('Month', fill_value=0) \
     ...:   .rename_axis(None, 1).reset_index()
     ...:
Out[206]:
     Fruit   1  3  12
0    Apple  61  6   0
1  Bananas  12  6   0
2     Kiwi  34  0   0
3    Melon   0  0  12
```

Comment: Thanks for both your solutions. One question though. Say I have both a "sales" and "revenue" column, and I wish to sum them up both. I managed to get this to work using pivot_table with the argument `values=['Sales','Revenue']`. 
However when I attempt this using unstack() it gives the error `TypeError: Must pass list-like as names`.

Is the unstack() function unfit to do an operation like this?

Comment: @Duudsrednaz, can you provide reproducible sample data set and desired data set?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the first post. I'm just wondering whether pivot_table or groupby is more suitable for this.

Comment: @Duudsrednaz, i've updated my answer - is that what you want?

Comment: That's it, thanks. I see `rename_axis` caused the TypeError, only I can't tell why. Could you help me understand why `rename_axis` is required in the first example, but not the last?

Comment: You essentially don't need `rename_axis` when using doing things a little differently after the `groupby`. Please see my updated answer @Duudsrednaz.